# Selecting Query Based on $_POST action to display while loop

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to run a query to extract user data to be used in a while loop. The first query is the default query which would run (or is suppose to run) regardless of $_POST. The second query runs only when ViewAllFriends button is submitted. Here is what I have in form:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
                <div class="panel panel-default friends">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h3 class="panel-title"><?php echo "<h4 style='font-family:Maven Pro;'>Friends of: <a href='" . $username ."'>" . $profile_user_obj->getFirstAndLastName() . "</a></h4><hr>"; ?></h3>

        <?php 
                global $con;
                $username = $_GET['profile_username'];

                //Default query limits results to 5
                $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE friend_array LIKE '$username,%' OR friend_array LIKE '%,$username,%' OR friend_array LIKE '%,$username' LIMIT 0,5");  

                //Query to run if button ViewAllFriends submitted
                if(isset($_POST['ViewAllFriends'])) {
                    $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE friend_array LIKE '$username,%' OR friend_array LIKE '%,$username,%' OR friend_array LIKE '%,$username'");            

        ?>
                        <div>
                          <div class="panel-body">
                            <ul>
                <?php
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                    $friends = $row['profile_pic']; 
                    $friend_username = $row['username'];
                ?>
                              <li><a class="thumbnail pull-left" href="<?php echo $friend_username; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $friends; ?>" title="<?php echo $friend_username; ?>"></a></li><?php } } ?>
                            </ul>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" id="ViewAllFriends" name="ViewAllFriends" value="View All Friends">
                          </div>
                        </div>     
                    </div><!-- End Panel Heading -->
                </div><!-- End Panel Friends -->
            </form>
```

Right now the first query does not run, IOW no profile pics are displayed. However when I submit the View All Friends button, all of the profile pics display. I'm not sure how to evaluate the first query to run as default? I tried the following:

```
if(empty($_POST[ViewAllFriends])){...}
```

But this would make the second query an else statement which is not correct logic since it is dependent on a user action.

Comment: You should use prepared statements instead of writing vars inside the queries to avoid SQL injection attacks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
global $con;
$username = $_GET['profile_username'];

if(isset($_POST['ViewAllFriends'])) {
    //Query to run if button ViewAllFriends submitted
    $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE friend_array LIKE '$username,%' OR friend_array LIKE '%,$username,%' OR friend_array LIKE '%,$username'"); 
} else {
    //Default query limits results to 5
    $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE friend_array LIKE '$username,%' OR friend_array LIKE '%,$username,%' OR friend_array LIKE '%,$username' LIMIT 0,5"); 
}
```

And now remove the extra bracket in:

```
<?php } } ?>
```

To:

```
<?php } ?>
```

After the thumbnails.

If it works consider changing the code to use prepared statements instead of writing variable values inside sql queries to prevent from SQL injection attacks.